# My own strcpy function

Tags: c, string

As a learning technique, i'm suppose to make my own copy of the following string function in

```
    char * mystrcpy(char *a, char *b);
// string copy.  destroys a but not b.
// identical to strcpy in <string.h>
// running time O(mystrlen(b))
```

I've come with this

```
char * mystrcpy(char *a, char *b){
a = b;
return a;

}
```

since `string a` is a random chuck in memory I'm thinking to assign just to `string b` ... is my interpretation correct ?

Comment: You need to at least **try**. We're not here to just do your homework for you. Write some code which you think might work, and come back and ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: @GrahamBorland: Though your comment is generally true, the OP clearly specifies what he intends to do and asks specific questions regarding it. He is not asking for someone to make his homework for him. IMO it's a valid question :\

Comment: Please don't make this approach to your homework [your M.O.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9771624/introduction-to-arrays) around here. Try to answer the question yourself. Show us what you've tried. Even if it's completely and utterly wrong.

Comment: sorry, i didnt want the answer, the question i asked in the end basically i wanted it to be confirmed.. So i could attempt to try somethings ? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

accessing a specific char [in index `i`] in string is done using `a[i]`, just like an array. [remember that in C, a string is actually an array of `char`s].

You should iterate the strings until you "see" a `'\0'` char - which indicate the end of string.

Yes, comparing to chars with `operator<` is comparing them by their ascii value - which is probably what you need.

Comment: say i have `char *u = "bbcdef";` if i wanted to access 'b' i would do u[0] ?

Comment: @Beginnernato: Yes, you can get the first 'b' using `u[0]`. Note that because your string in here is a string literal you can only read `u[0]`  and not change it.

Comment: @Beginnernato `*b != '\0'` [in the loop's stop condition] checks only for the first element in the array, you are probably looking for `b[i] != '\0'`. also, in the first check of the loop: `(i > strlen(a)` You need `<=`, remember arrays [and strings] are starting from 0, not 1.

Comment: any suggestion what i should do with `mystrcpy` , (Updated question)

Comment: @Beginnernato you should loop and copy each character using the same ideas from b to a

Comment: Ohh i see, uhh for the last one strcat .. i got this http://ideone.com/wLeTP <-- it doesn't seem to work, how come ? :(